# What Time Zone is used for Marketing Clouds Guided Send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, timezone

I'm wondering if someone knows what time zone is used during Email Guided Send?

You can setup time zone for each Business Unit and User separately. I run some tests and it looks that Marketing Cloud picks every time lover GMT zone from those two (example: from GMT+0 and GMT+2 it will pick up GMT+0).

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently based on the logged in user's timezone and it's not an ideal solution.

[image]

Unfortunately, it's not possible to assign a timezone manually as yet. There's [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LkffQAC) idea which is 'Under Point Threshold' - so it will help voting it up.

[image]